# Finding interval with exact probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and we have an interval $[a,b]$ with $\mathbb{P}([a,b])>\epsilon$. Is there a value $a<r<b$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}([a,r])=\epsilon$?

Comment: For sure. Define $f(r) := P([a,r])$ and use Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @obareey who said its continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the assumptions on your distribution. If, say, the distribution is given in terms of its cumulative distribution function $g(x):= \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$, and if $g(x)$ is continuous, then your result holds by the intermediate value theorem (applied to the function $h(x) = g(x) - g(a)$ on the interval $[a,b]$).

But if $g(x)$ is given by a step function for example, say $g(x) = \chi_{[(a+b)/2,\,\infty)}(x)$, then you can easily see that the result doesn't hold.